# how can i fix strange char php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

In my php page, by a mysql database query, I got this type of char: �
I am using utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
I am using Mysql (no PDO or Mysqlì)
I am desperate and I don't know how I can fix it.
Could you help me, please? Thank you!

**EDIT:** I found a solution using this in my html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

I tried also charset=utf-8 but it's not working.
Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: change your table charset from `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Comment: utf8mb4_unicode_ci is definitely better than utf8_unicode_ci so I don't think that's the issue...

Comment: @SamuelCloete Do you think my answer will work or not? I think this is a good way because I worked with many right-to-left languages like Persian and I had no problem with this way!

Comment: @Marci if possible could you show the data that is returning this char(a sql dump for that row of table would suffice). If you have used excel to copy and paste data into mysql table columns then it might have been the issue.

Comment: Just checking.... Is your HTML set to UTF-8?

Comment: @Kermani, using utf8mb4 is generally considered safer... in PHP use multibyte string functions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Comment: @SamuelCloete But Samuel, I think what I write will work and can solve his problem as you said it is not as safe as  utf8mb4. Thanks for information!

Comment: Guys, thank you very much for your answers, I edited my first post with a solution :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");` before your query may solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your database char set collection to a UTF-8 collection like [**`utf8_general_ci`**](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748) and for your *php* connection you have to use [**`mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8")`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)

LIKE:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Change character set to utf8
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two wrongs don't make a right.  What you have now will handle latin1 text, but not all of utf8mb4.

You probably have

- latin1 bytes in the client (not full utf8)
- `SET NAMES latin1`, probably by default.  (need utf8mb4)
- `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` on the tables/columns (good)
- `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">` -- good for now, but will break when you fix the first two items.

(Black diamond with question mark)